# Segfault error 4 in libmysqlclient.so

Tags: mysql, segmentation-fault

Since a few days, I see this kind of messages in my syslog:

```
Sep 23 14:28:42 server kernel: [138926.637593] php5-fpm[6455]: segfault at 7f9ade735018 ip 00007f9ae4026772 sp 00007ffd69b4fad0 error 4 in libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0[7f9ae3ff9000+2f1000]
Sep 23 14:28:44 server kernel: [138928.314016] php5-fpm[22742]: segfault at 7f9ade3db018 ip 00007f9ae4026772 sp 00007ffd69b4fad0 error 4 in libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0[7f9ae3ff9000+2f1000]
Sep 23 14:32:11 server kernel: [139135.318287] php5-fpm[16887]: segfault at 7f9ade4b3018 ip 00007f9ae4026772 sp 00007ffd69b4fad0 error 4 in libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0[7f9ae3ff9000+2f1000]
Sep 23 14:32:49 server kernel: [139173.050377] php5-fpm[668]: segfault at 7f9ade61a018 ip 00007f9ae4026772 sp 00007ffd69b4fad0 error 4 in libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0[7f9ae3ff9000+2f1000]
Sep 23 14:33:19 server kernel: [139203.396935] php5-fpm[26277]: segfault at 7f9ade6c0018 ip 00007f9ae4026772 sp 00007ffd69b4fad0 error 4 in libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0[7f9ae3ff9000+2f1000]
Sep 23 14:35:06 server kernel: [139310.048740] php5-fpm[27017]: segfault at 7f9ade46c018 ip 00007f9ae4026772 sp 00007ffd69b4fad0 error 4 in libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0[7f9ae3ff9000+2f1000]
Sep 23 14:35:19 server kernel: [139323.494188] php5-fpm[31263]: segfault at 7f9ade5e2018 ip 00007f9ae4026772 sp 00007ffd69b4fad0 error 4 in libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0[7f9ae3ff9000+2f1000]
Sep 23 14:36:10 server kernel: [139374.904308] php5-fpm[26422]: segfault at 7f9ade6cf018 ip 00007f9ae4026772 sp 00007ffd69b4fad0 error 4 in libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0[7f9ae3ff9000+2f1000]
Sep 23 14:37:25 server kernel: [139449.360384] php5-fpm[20806]: segfault at 7f9ade644018 ip 00007f9ae4026772 sp 00007ffd69b4fad0 error 4 in libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0[7f9ae3ff9000+2f1000]
```

I'm using debian 8 and MariaDB.
In the beginning it was only once every 2 or 3 hours, but now it's several times per hours. 
After some research, I understand as it should be an memory problem, but I didn't find any solution to solve it.

This is what I see in mysqltuner:

```
-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +Aria +BLACKHOLE +CSV +FEDERATED +InnoDB +MRG_MyISAM 
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 2G (Tables: 79)
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 96M (Tables: 146)
[--] Data in PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA tables: 0B (Tables: 52)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 34

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 1d 16h 44m 38s (73M q [502.853 qps], 196K conn, TX: 572B, RX: 14B)
[--] Reads / Writes: 97% / 3%
[--] Total buffers: 17.3G global + 56.2M per thread (500 max threads)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 44.8G (142% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (2K/73M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 28% (141/500)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 1.0G/32.6M
[OK] Key buffer hit rate: 100.0% (132M cached / 53K reads)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 44.9% (50M cached / 113M selects)
[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 260596
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (2K temp sorts / 2M sorts)
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 21% (6K on disk / 28K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (141 created / 196K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 72% (500 open / 692 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 17% (429/2K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (25M immediate / 25M locks)
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 16.0G/2.4G
[!!] InnoDB log waits: 30
```

So the maximum memory to use is too high, but I ajusted my innodb buffer pool size to 16Go, for 32Go RAM that should be ok, I don't know what to do for optimize this.

The thing is, my memory general usage in the server is always under 89% (plus for caching).
MySQL is actually using 50,6% of RAM.
I don't know if there is link between all of this, but I prefere to put it here. Otherwise, everything seems to be ok in MySQL side...

Finally this the principal variables in my.cnf I adjusted which could have an effect on this:

```
max_connections = 100
max_heap_table_size = 64M
read_buffer_size = 4M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 32M
sort_buffer_size = 8M
query_cache_size = 256M
query_cache_limit = 4M
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_strip_comments =1
thread_stack = 192K
transaction_isolation = READ-COMMITTED
tmp_table_size = 64M
nnodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 16M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16G
thread_cache_size   = 4M
max_connections     = 500
join_buffer_size    = 12M
interactive_timeout = 30
wait_timeout        = 30
open_files_limit    = 800
innodb_file_per_table
key_buffer_size     = 1G
table_open_cache    = 500
innodb_log_file_size    = 256M
```

Two days ago the server crashed for no reason in syslog execpt the segfault.
Can segfault crash the system ?
Any Idea for the segfault reason ? A few ways to understand the origin of the problem ?

Comment: You didn't specified the distribution. I'd suggest to enable core dumps so next time you get more info, what really happened. In case you got out of memory, there would be something about OOM killer (Out Of Memory) in logs (grep -i 'killed process').

Comment: *"After some research, I understand as it should be an memory problem."*  There's no evidence for that.  These log entries point only to a problem with the MySQL *client* software and php, not the server.  Check your web server logs for a page throwing errors to narrow it down.

Comment: My distribution is Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie). Can you explain what is core dump and why should I enable it ? As explain in another topic I enabled core dump with this command:`ulimit -c unlimited`. I don't if I should do another thing ...

Comment: So you thing it's not a server side problem but a client side ? That's mean the problem could be in the query in my website ? I don't see particular errors in link with that.

Comment: For information, I solved this problem by resolving another problem, in htis thread: https://serverfault.com/questions/875192/mysql-maximum-possible-memory-usage-above-installed-ram

Comment: The answer for this issue is in this topic: [https://serverfault.com/questions/875192/mysql-maximum-possible-memory-usage-above-installed-ram](https://serverfault.com/questions/875192/mysql-maximum-possible-memory-usage-above-installed-ram)

Comment: The answer for this issue is in this another topic: https://serverfault.com/questions/875192/mysql-maximum-possible-memory-usage-above-installed-ram